# generic object type conversion (From type object to Specific Class)

Tags: c#, generics, casting, type-conversion

**Entity**

```
public class CompareParameter<T>
{
    public string FieldName { get; set; }
    public T FieldValue { get; set; }
    public CompareType CompareType { get; set; }
}
```

**Interface**

```
public interface IMongoConnectionFactory
{
   int GetCountWithFilter<T>(params object[] param) where T:EntityBase;
}
```

**Interface Implementation**

```
public class MongoConnectionFactory : IMongoConnectionFactory
{
    public int GetCountWithFilter<T>(params object[] param) where T : RedBusPlusEntities.EntityBase
    {
        throw new NotImplementationException();
    }
}
```

**Business Code**

```
public int GetCustomerCount(int operatorId, int day)
{
    Customer c = new Customer();

    CompareParameter<int> OpId = new CompareParameter<int>();
    OpId.FieldName=GetMemberName.GetName(() => c.OpId);
    OpId.FieldValue=operatorId;
    OpId.CompareType=CompareType.EQ;

    CompareParameter<long> Day = new CompareParameter<long>();
    Day.FieldName=GetMemberName.GetName(() => c.Doil);
    Day.FieldValue=GetStartDateOfIssue(day);
    Day.CompareType = CompareType.GTE;

    return _fac.GetCountWithFilter<Customer>(OpId, Day);
}
```

So here i'm passing two param of two different type from Business to DAL. So i am passing it in from of `object`. Now how do i construct the same type that was passed in the implementation of the interface. Tried some approach with `Convert.ChangeType` but failed. Can somebody assist me on that?

Comment: it would be helpful to know what you are doing within int GetCountWithFilter<T>(params object[] param) because it may be possible to pass in something other than object[]

Comment: I am trying to create a mongo filter query by passing the param object. mongo query looks like `var filter = builder.Eq("cuisine", "Italian") & builder.Eq("zip", 10075);` Passed object contains necessary information and type for creation of filter

Comment: so could you not change your interface to be:
   public interface IMongoConnectionFactory
    {
       int GetCountWithFilter<T>(params CompareParameter<T>[] param) where T:EntityBase;
    }

Comment: @ScottMorken In `params CompareParameter<T>[] param` T is different than T of GetCountWithFilter. and also as you can see from the `CompareParameter` entity definition T for this entity would differ from object to object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you have a method - `GetCountWithFilter<T>` and the parameters could be of different types, so you're passing them as `object` and then you'll figure out later what the actual types are?

My recommendation is don't do it. To pass parameters as `object`, allow callers to pass *anything* and then inspect the parameters to determine their type defeats the purpose of a strongly-typed language. Even if the type isn't `object` (it's an interface) you still don't want to have to figure out at runtime what the actual type is.

The method signatures of an interface or class describe how consumers should use it. If the parameters are of type `object` then a consumer can't tell what the "right" types are to pass.

Can you create a parameter type that's inclusive of what the consumers need to pass?
Or, can you create two methods on your interface reflecting the exact types of the parameters to pass?

If you can't, then perhaps the two different behaviors can't be described by one interface.

---

Having said all that, here's a direct answer:

In `GetCountWithFilter` you'd have to check each object to see what its type is. Something like this:

```
if(param.length==2 
    && param[0] is CompareParameter<int>
    && param[1] is int)
{
    var param1 = (CompareParameter<int>)param[0];
    var param2 = (int)param[1];
    //Now you have your parameters cast as their original types.
}
```